# Is it a bad practice to add a listener in a block of code executed multiple times?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have the following question: let's say I have a function named `hi` and a button named `btn`.

What will the following code produce?

```
fun hi(){
    Btn.setOnClickListener { /*something */ }
}
```

Comment: The title "*is it bad to call a listener in a block ...*" is not the same as you are asking in the question "*what the following code doing*"  -  Why such a title that is not related to the question?

Comment: Its function meaning that could be called multiple times

Comment: @Dan `{ }` braces were correct and the semicolon is non-standard in Kotlin.

Comment: my bad, didn't read the tags properly. Missed noticing it was in kotlin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time the method is called, the listener is being reset.

This means that there will not be multiple calls once the `Btn` is clicked.

Usually click listeners are set only one time.

The cost of each call is creating a new instance of `OnClickListener`